On a metrized $n$-dimensional manifold $X$, does every $x \in X$ have a small ball $B_\delta(x)$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?
Suppose that $X$ is an $n$-dimensional topological manifold that is also metrizable, and hence equipped with some metric that induces the topology.
For every point $x \in X$, let $B_\delta(x)$ be the open unit ball around $x$ with radius $\delta > 0$.
Q: Under what conditions does every $x \in X$ admit arbitrarily small $\delta > 0$ such that the open ball $B_\delta(x)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?
Upon choosing $\delta > 0$ small enough, we can suppose that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq U_x$, where $U_x \subseteq X$ is an open set and there exists a homeomorphism $ \phi : U_x \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ satisfying $\phi(x)=0$. The metric can be transported to $\mathbb R^n$, which then has finite diameter. We can then ask:
Q: Suppose that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb R^n$ that induces the topology and gives that space a finite diameter. Do there there exist arbitrary small $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(0) \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is itself homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?
I am wondering whether this is too strong in the general topological category, whether there are some pathological counterexamples.
I also welcome conditions that rule pathological counterexamples.

If $\mathbb R^n$ has finite diameter $r$ with respect to $d$ then the open ball with radius $2r$ is all of $\mathbb R^n$, isn't it?

I hope I have clarified the question.

Consider $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$. Then $$d(x,y)=|x-y|+|f(x)-f(y)|$$
defines a metric on $\mathbb R$ which induces the usual topology (because of the continuity of $f$) but no $d$-ball around $0$ is connected.

Edit. As noted by Achim Krause, this works for small radii. His comment describes how to get the same phenomenon for all balls.

Small addition: No $d$-ball around $0$ of small radius ($<0.258$) is connected, for large radius they of course are. One can fix this by letting $t(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x<\frac{1}{10}$, and $t(x)=10 - 100(x-\frac{1}{10})$ for $x\geq \frac{1}{10}$, and setting $f(x)=x\sin(t(x))$. This ensures that $f$ keeps oscillating fast enough also for large $|x|$.

Regarding the first question: if the metric is the Carnot-Caratheodory metric on step-two sub-Riemannian manifolds, small balls should be homeomorphic to standard balls.
(It is known that Carnot-Caratheodory metrics induce the manifold topology, see Theorem 3.31 here)
This should follow from the main result of this paper:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000390050008
Here the author proves that, in the step-two case, small Carnot-Caratheodory spheres are homeomporhic to standard spheres. If this homeomorphism would depend continuously on the radius (which seems to be the case, at least from skimming the proof quickly), then, by the generalized Schoenflies Theorem (as stated in Theorem 5 from Brown's paper https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1960-66-02/S0002-9904-1960-10400-4/) this should imply that small Carnot-Caratheodory balls are homeomorphic to standard balls.
In the general sub-Riemannian case, whether small balls are even just contractible seems still to be an open problem.

Here is, as  an example, a sort of "mosquito coil" shaped curve $X\sim\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R^3$, endowed with the induced Euclidean norm.
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb R^2$ a pressed logarithmic spiral with polar equations, for $\theta\in\mathbb R.$
$$ \rho(\theta)= \sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\mu^2\,\sin^2\theta}\,e^{\theta},$$
with $0<\mu<e^{\frac{3\pi}2}$, for instance $\mu=\frac1{112}$.
The intersection of $\Gamma$ with every Euclidian disc centered at the  origin is disconnected: it is sufficient to  observe that every positive sub-level set of the function $ \rho:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is disconnected, and this is  true just because $\rho(-\infty)=0$, $\rho(+\infty)=+\infty$ and, on the sequence of integer multiples of $\frac\pi2$, one has $$\rho(k\pi)=e^{k\pi} >   \rho\big(k\pi+\frac {3\pi}2\big)=\mu e^{k\pi+\frac {3\pi}2}$$ (draw the zig-zag shape of the graph of $\rho$ if the conclusion is not clear).
Finally, define $X:=\big(\Gamma\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big(\{(0,0)\}\times[0,+\infty)\big)\subset\mathbb R^3$. Then $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and no ball in the metric induced by the Euclidean norm, centered at $(0,0,0)\in X$ is connected.

After thinking, a simpler example is the graph $G\subset \mathbb R^2$ of $f(x):=x\sin e^{\lambda x}$ with the metric induced by the Euclidean distance.  If $\lambda$ is large enough,  every ball of $G$ at the origin has more that $1000$ components. But this  is essentially Jochen Wengenroth's example
